# handwaving substitution in integral involving branch cut and derivative of sqrt + generalization

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, branch-cuts

Want to compute
$$ I = \int_0^i \mathrm{d}z \frac{z}{\sqrt{z^2-1}}$$
on the complex plane using complex methods.

QUESTION: is the result $i \left( \sqrt{2}-1 \right)$ which one gets imposing $\arg\in[0,2\pi)$ the only possible one?

Perhaps, I can post here a GENERALIZATION of my previous question:
Prove that one can define a branch of the function $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ in every region $D\subset \mathbb{C}$ such that the points $-1$ and 1 belong to the same connected component of the complement of $D.$
How many values can the integral
$$\int_\gamma \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$$
take along a closed path $\gamma$ contained in $D$ ?

Comment: What is the meaning of $\int \limits _o^{\color {red} i}f(z)\, \mathrm dz$?

Comment: it is integral over complex plane, along imaginary segment from 0 to 1. i guess from your question that the answer to my first question is no

Comment: @GitGud whenever you have an antiderivative only the start and the end point is of interest

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: in this case, you have to be careful about what branch of the square root you are on.  See my answer below.

Comment: @RonGordon those branch cuts are an ugly thing :D

Answer (score 2):

The integrand has a primitive $\sqrt{z^2-1}$. That said, you need to be careful with the being on a consistent branch of the square root throughout the integration interval.  Other than that, it doesn't matter what the contour is.

Assume we are on a branch of the square root such that $\sqrt{-1}=i$.  Then the integral is

$$  \sqrt{-2}-\sqrt{-1} = (\sqrt{2}-1) i$$

**EDIT**

What if we do cross a branch cut?  Assume we do at $z=i a$ where $0<a<1$.  Then if the second branch is $\sqrt{-1}=-i$, then the integral has value

$$\left (\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1+a^2}\right) (-i) + \left ( \sqrt{1+a^2}-1\right) i$$

Comment: i don't get it: is it the answer supposed to be unique, if the only piece of information i'm given is the above one?

Comment: @Nicolo': it might not be unique because you could easily choose a contour that passes through a branch cut.  You have no info on what  contour to choose, just endpoints of an integral.  (Maybe in your class, you're supposed to assume integration on a straight line, but that still doesn't answer the question about how the square root is defined.)

Comment: i understand; no, i'm not supposed to pick a straight line, but i thought that the procedure of picking a branch cut and then an integration path and applying residue theory would give a unique answer, independent of the choice (clever or not) of branch cut

Comment: @Nicolo': again, you have a primitive so you can evaluate at endpoints...but you need to know that you have chosen a contour that defines a consistent branch of the square root.

Comment: can you explain a little bit the second case? even if the path doesn't matter, you should still specify one along which you integrate and you can't cross whatever branch cut you've done, right?

Comment: @Nicolo': that's the point.  Because you specified nothing, I could go along whatever path I liked.  If I did have some bizarre cut like the one I described, then you have to treat the branch cut discontinuity as I did.